# How to test deep link in iOS simulator with Appium

Tags: ios, safari, automation, appium, simulator

I want to automate the tests of deep link with Appium on the iOS simulator. Do you have any advice, how you do that ?

This is where I go : 
For testing the deep link with the simulator, I want to open the Safari app. 
So now I use the function `runAppInBackground` to back home of the simulator.
Then I want to open an URL with Safari, but the `driver.get("http://www.google.com)` doesn't work. I tried to tap on the safari button in the home, but still doesn't work :(
When I check the `getContextHandles`, I only have `[NATIVE_APP]`

Any idea ? Any other way to test the deep links ?

Thanks in advance for you help ! :)

Comment: your question has too many sub questions please make it clear, so we try to answer.

Comment: My general question is Howto test the deep link. I tell which solution I've tried to use to test the deep link, but there's maybe a better solution.

Comment: my understandings of deep link is "is there any web view in app or not " you want to see when app get launched, i don't think there will be an answer for that.

Comment: Oh, yeah.. We've donne a huge research with developers, and it seems to be impossible. Appium use Instruments, and Instruments prevent to switch between apps..
So we're gonna develop a webview inside the app, it seems to be the only way to test the deep links.

Comment: @JulienBlc did you have a chance to find any solution?

Comment: @olyv Unfortunately i didn't found any solution.. The mobile devs in my company developed an intern feature to use deep link. The feature is hidden (special code to pop it) and then a text field to use the deep links

Comment: @JulienBlcju thanks for your response. If I find a solution, I'll update you

Comment: @JulienBlc Hi, it works for me with simple `driver.get()`. I prepared example in http://olyv-qa.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/appium-ios-deep-link.html